# Using the comparison test to determine series' convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm having trouble figuring out how to use the comparison test to check if an infinite series converges or diverges. I put two problems that I have to solve, does anyone have any input on this? The main problem I keep facing is trying to figure out what series to compare with, any tips on this would be appreciated!

Note: the sum goes from n=1 to infinity.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First one:
$$
\frac{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt n}{n}=\frac{1}{n(\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt n)}.
$$
The numerator has degree $0$; the denominaror $3/2$ (1+1/2.) Compare with $\sum 1/n^{3/2}$.

Second one: numeratos has degree $6$; denominator $8$. Compare with $\sum 1/n^2$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can we assume the first equality to hold? I am testing it for the numbers n=1, n=4 and n=9 and from what I can tell this equality does not hold.

Comment: There was an typo ($-$instead of $+$.) I have corrected it.

Comment: I just noticed it was a typo indeed, this answers my questions. Thanks again.